VBA - Accessing items in a nested dictionary
I have the following table laid out in an excel worksheet named "Mapping"



Funds
Portfolio
Structure
LocationAccount




F1
Fund 1
Cash
Acct_1


F2
Fund 2
Cash
Acct_2


F3
Fund 3
Cash
Acct_3



In the below code i am trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries however the last line of code is kicking out an error: 424 Object Required.  How do i access the elements inside the dictionary?
Sub build_dictionary()
    
    
    Dim funds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim mapping As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim fund As Variant
    
    'funds represents the outer dictionary
    Set funds = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    'mapping represents the inner dictionary
    Set mapping = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For Each fund In Worksheets("Mapping").Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Cells
        
        'set key value pairs to the mapping(inner) dictionary
        mapping.Add "portfolio", fund.Offset(0, 1).Value
        mapping.Add "structure", fund.Offset(0, 2).Value
        mapping.Add "locationaccount", fund.Offset(0, 3).Value
        
        'in the outer dictionary set key=fund, item = mapping dictionary
        funds.Add fund, mapping
        
        'remove all key-value pairs of mapping dictionary in preparation of next loop
        mapping.RemoveAll
           
    Next fund
    
    'produces error '424' Object required
    Debug.Print funds("F1").Item("portfolio")
    

End Sub


funds.Add fund.Value, mapping otherwise the key you're adding is the Range object itself, not the value of that cell.  Once you do that though you'll see you now have another problem: all the dictionaries are empty (and they all point to the same object).

Range("a2").End(xlDown) refers to the Active worksheet, which may, or may not be the same as Worksheets("Mapping")

Scripting dictionary accepts keys of any type, including Object, so with funds.Add fund, mapping the key you're adding is the Range object itself, not the value of that cell. This is a case where relying on the default property of Value doesn't get you what you expect.
Your inner dictionaries still all point to the same object mapping though, and you clear that every time through the loop, so your inner dictionary is empty.
Make a fresh dictionary each time:
Sub build_dictionary()
    
    Dim funds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim fund As Range, fundName As String
    
    Set funds = New Scripting.Dictionary 'funds represents the outer dictionary
    
    For Each fund In Worksheets("Mapping").Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Cells
        fundName = fund.Value
        funds.Add fundName, New Scripting.Dictionary 'create a fresh dict
        With funds(fundName) 'set key value pairs to the inner dictionary
            .Add "portfolio", fund.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Add "structure", fund.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Add "locationaccount", fund.Offset(0, 3).Value
        End With
    Next fund
    
    Debug.Print funds("F1").Item("portfolio") '>> Fund 1
    Debug.Print funds("F2").Item("structure") '>> Cash
    
End Sub

